# Excel, repeat strings with number based on comparing first column's value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

here is what i try to do, i have this table here, shot, asset and instance name.
[image: before]

and based on Shot column and also look up Asset column, it fills the Instance Name column as:
[image: after]

so within a range of shot (say 101_010_010), apple repeated twice, therefore in the Instance Name column shows apple01, apple02.

but within next range of shot, apple shows only once, therefore in the Instance Name column, it shows as apple. (apple01).

I tried to use Match mixed with vlookup, but I cant make it work as I wanna to.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS` and [mixed references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9).

In `C2`:

```
=B2&IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)>1,TEXT(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2),"00"),"")
```

[image]